Can a chain of implications be solved using calc in Lean 4?
I have seen the lean calc tactic being used on a chain of (in)equalities (=, <) and logical equivalences (<->), to finally form a proof. And I found it really convenient.
But can this chaining of calc being done for logical implications as well?
For example, in the small proof of the transitivity of the subset relation (⊆) below,
given three sets r, s, t and
given x ∈ r,
one can conclude x ∈ s ( r ⊆ s),
and then conclude x ∈ t (s ⊆ t)
I can proof it by formulating the proof term directly:
import Mathlib.Data.Nat.Prime.Basic

section

variable {α : Type*} (r s t : Set α)

theorem Subset.trans : r ⊆ s → s ⊆ t → r ⊆ t :=
  fun rs st x xr ↦ st (rs xr)

end

But I think using a chain in the calc style (as follows) is more readable:
theorem Subset.trans' : r ⊆ s → s ⊆ t → r ⊆ t :=
  fun rs st x xr ↦
    calc x ∈ r
      _ → x ∈ s  := by sorry
      _ → x ∈ t  := by sorry

This does not work, as Lean 4 complains at the first implication (→) line

invalid 'calc' step, relation expected   ?m.194 → x ∈ sLean 4

My question is why the error occurs and whether/how can calc (or a similar command) be used to chain a sequence of implications as in above?

Unfortunately → is not an infix, it's a special builtin syntax (which makes sense because you have dependent types etc). If you define an infix operator for implication, and provide the relevant Transitivity type class, then you can use calc blocks for it:
def Imply (a b : Prop) := a → b

instance transImply : Trans Imply Imply Imply where
  trans := fun f g x => g (f x)

infix:20 "==>" => Imply

theorem fish {a b c : Prop} : a → a ∨ b ∨ c := by
  calc
    a ==> a ∨ b      := by { intro ; left ; assumption }
    _ ==> a ∨ b ∨ c  := by { rintro (p | q) ; exact Or.inl p ; exact Or.inr (Or.inl q) }


I took the liberty of making your answer explicit, as it seemed pointless to write another anwer. Please change my edits if you dislike them.
